# Facebook OG Display Won't Generate; Code works with different domain

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, blocked

I coded a URL shorter for our application that utilizes a PHP Header Location to redirect the page.

When I try use the Sharing Debugger on our production domain I get the following message: URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

However when I try using our development domain; it works as planned.  Both domains are running the same code.

Is my domain blocked?

Answer (score 0):

when you make use of Facebook apis you must be registering them as a facebook app, so what happened might be, you have registered your application with the development domain (your current working copy), but never registered the actual domain. So what you need might need to do is register a new facebook application with your production domain. since you register a new application for the production, then you will be having different API keys and you might need to update them accordingly.

Comment: Both domains are registered with my API keys, I don't believe this issue is related to the API because it happens with I goto share the link as a status in Facebook as well.